# Evaluate formula and remove formula from cell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to evaluate formula and the remove the formula from the cell keeping its values. How can this be done using Apache POI ?

Below is my code where I evaluate all the formulas.

```
        FormulaEvaluator evaluator = template.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        int sheetCount = template.getNumberOfSheets();
        for(int sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < sheetCount; sheetIndex ++) {
            sheet = dfaTemplate.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);
            for (Row r : sheet) {
                for (Cell c : r) {
                    if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
                        evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried `evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell)`? See https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#evaluateFormulaCell(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell).

Comment: @Priyesh: maybe you should write that as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell)` instead of `evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(c)`. If the cell contains a formula, **evaluateInCell** evaluates the formula, and puts the formula result back into the cell, in place of the old formula.

See [evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#evaluateFormulaCell(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell)) for further information.